# In Go, how to import function directly, without need to prefix with the package name when I call it?

Tags: go

In the Go programming language, why after importing a package do I still have to prefix a method within that package with the package name?

i.e.

```
import "io/ioutil"

func main() { 
    content, err = iotuil.ReadFile("somefile.txt")
    // etc..
}
```

Isn't this redundant? In Java, for example, you can do things like importing `Files.readAllLines` etc without having `Files` imported.

Comment: I just tried to do a Files.readAllLines without having Files imported and it didn't compile. I can't find anything that says that the java.nio.file package is automatically imported.

Comment: the import is ioutil, but the package name is iotuil, is that a typo? Could fix that if it is or clarify it to me please. Thnx

Comment: The GopherCon 2014 keynote speech by Rob Pike (one of the languages creators) is a really interesting introduction to the thought processes that went in to designing the language. It covers the package system (in short, they did it for readability). Well worth a watch. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoS7DsT1rdM

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I guess this doesn't really answer your question, but if you want, you can actually call the methods without explicitly stating the package - just import with a `.` in front of the names (but this is not recommended; see below):

```
package main

import (
  . "fmt"
  . "io/ioutil"
)

func main () {
  content, err := ReadFile("testfile")
  if err != nil {
    Println("Errors")
  }
  Println("My file:\n", string(content))
}
```

Note @jimt's comment below - this practice is **not** advised outside of tests as it could cause name conflicts with future releases. Also, definitely agree with @DavidGrayson's point of being nicer to read/see where things come from.

Comment: It should be noted that the dot-import is not considered good practice.

From [golang.org](http://golang.org/doc/go1compat.html): If a program imports a standard package using `import . "path"`, additional names defined in the imported package in future releases may conflict with other names defined in the program. We do not recommend the use of `import .` outside of tests, and using it may cause a program to fail to compile in future releases.

Comment: @jimt Awesome, thanks for that (it just felt wrong for some reason, glad that is actually isn't advised :) ). I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: If golang.org has an objection to import . "path" they should remove it from the language. Why would it be a good thing to use for tests ("outside of tests...")? Aren't tests kept forever these days?  And the . import, is exactly what every import statement in Java does. In fact, that is all import statements in Java do. I don't see much java code that isn't doing a ". import".

Comment: Java isn't Go. The dot-import is in the language for much the same reasons the builtin `print` and `println` are still in there (legacy and bootstrapping). They too are not intended for production use and may disappear into thin air at any time.

Comment: @jimt Java and go aren't the only languages that have a way of adding an extra global qualifier to functions and classes. C++ and C# have namespaces and you will see plenty of people "using namespace xxx" in order to remove the global prefix data. The reason go and C++, C# and Java and Python and everybody else give the capability to remove the prefix is because most of the time it is not necessary. And when it is, it is easily added in to solve the problem of a name clash. So it should be, "Go is not Java or C++, or C# or Python or...".  But it does get rid of the debate if it goes.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it shouldn't do any harm if you have project-specific code that you spread across multiple files which you would otherwise have in your main package. But standard- and 3rd party libraries should have the namespace prefix to avoid naming collision.

Answer (score 58):

you can import and rename the package name, eg:

```
    import (  
        .     "fmt"       // no name, import in scope  
        File  "io/ioutil" // rename ioutil to File
        _     "net"       // net will not be available, but init() inside net package will be executed
    )
```

See also https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations

Answer (score 9):

I can't really speak for the designers of the Go language, but it is nice to be able to quickly tell where the method you are calling is defined.  It is also nice to see a list of all the packages your are using at the top of the file.  This is not redundant.

As you said, Java requires you to say `Files.readAllLines` and similarly go requires you to write `ioutil.ReadFile`.

Comment: Files in Files.readAllLines is not a package name. It is a class name being used to call a static method. The package for Files is java.nio.file, so without an import java.nio.file.Files; you would have to say: java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines()

Answer (score 1):

Import statements in go are not like in java, more like `#include` in c++. In go, if something isn't imported, you can't use it. If it is imported, you can use it but must be prefixed with the package name. As everyone else said, use `import . "packagename"` to import a package and not have to prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a (function) variable in your package (defined at package level, using the "var" keyword) with the desired name set to the imported function. Example:

`var ReadFile = ioutil.ReadFile`