# What's C++'s `using` equivalent in golang

Tags: c++, go, namespaces

What's C++'s `using some_namespace::object` equivalent in golang?

According to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925450/importing-packages-in-go) 
I can get `using namespace common` with statement below:

```
import (
  . "common"
)
```

But this would import the entire namespace. Right now I only want to use, say `platform` definition, something like `using common::platform`

Is there an equivalent for this in Go, so that I don't have to type `common.platform` all the time?

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm pretty sure the OP is looking for something like `using std::cout;` and then just be able toy use `cout` instead of `std::cout`.

Comment: @NathanOliver that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: If package naming and naming of exported stuff is well matched it is not much extra typing but a lot of extra readability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code comes close in terms of readability, but is less efficient, since the compiler cannot inline function calls anymore.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

var (
    Sprintf = fmt.Sprintf
    HasPrefix = strings.HasPrefix
)
```

And, it has the side-effect of importing the names `fmt` and `strings` into the file scope, which is something that C++'s `using` does not do.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no such functionality in Go.

That's not to say it will never be added: there is [open proposal to add "Alias declarations"](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16339) to the language.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, it is not possible in Go. In Go you import *packages*, not functions or types from packages.

Note that you can easily achieve what you want if you create a *helper* package.

Let's say you want "using" the [`fmt.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) and [`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) functions only. Create a helper package:

```
package helper

import "fmt"

func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error) {
    return fmt.Println(a...)
}

func Printf(format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error) {
    return fmt.Printf(format, a...)
}
```

And where you want the C++'s "using" functionality, import using a dot `.`:

```
import . "helper"

func Something() {
    Println("Hi")
    Printf("Using format string: %d", 3)
}
```

The result is that only the exported identifiers of the `helper` package will be in scope, nothing else from the `fmt` package. You can use this single `helper` package to make functions available from packages other than `fmt` of course, too. `helper` can import any other packages and have a "proxy" or delegator function publishing their functionality.

Personally I don't feel the need of this. I would just import `fmt` and call its functions using `fmt.Println()` and `fmt.Printf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could rename the package:

```golang
import ( 
     c "common"
     cout2 "github.com/one/cout" 
     cout2 "github.com/two/cout"
)
```

Then you would only have to type `c.Platform`