# How to access a struct from an external package in Go

Tags: go, struct, import

I'm trying to import a struct from another package in the following file:

```
// main.go
import "path/to/models/product"    
product = Product{Name: "Shoes"}

// models/product.go
type Product struct{
 Name string
}
```

But in the `main.go` file the struct `Product` is undefined. How do I import the struct?

Comment: Could just be an incomplete example but `product = Product{Name: "Shoes"}` isn't a valid statement so you may be misinterpreting the error. You need to use `:=` in that assignment because `product` isn't previously declared.

Answer (score 9):

In Go you import "complete" *packages*, not functions or types from packages.
(See this related question for more details: [What's C++'s `using` equivalent in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38904423/whats-cs-using-equivalent-in-golang))

See [Spec: Import declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations) for syntax and deeper explanation of the `import` keyword and import declarations.

Once you import a package, you may refer to its [exported identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) with [qualified identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers) which has the form: `packageName.Identifier`.

So your example could look like this:

```
import "path/to/models/product"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    p := product.Product{Name: "Shoes"}
    // Use product, e.g. print it:
    fmt.Println(p) // This requires `import "fmt"`
}
```

Comment: if I import the models folder with the `.` preceding the import and used the struct `Post` in the following method `func (p *Post) All(){fmt.Println("foo")}` it still shows up undefined though??

Comment: @ColleenLarsen Using "dot-import" is not recommended (only for testing purposes) because whether it works or not depends on how and from where you try to compile/run the code.

Comment: Ok using the same method having removed the `.` on the import as `func (p *models.Post)` the `models` is undefined for some reason?

Comment: @ColleenLarsen Your `product.go` must be in `$GOPATH/src/models`.

Comment: I have updated the question,  with the path to models correctly represented. but I still get the error

Comment: @ColleenLarsen Then please post your "file system view", meaning what files you have and in what folders. Most likely you have them in the wrong folder.

Comment: @icza The import was successful, so the problem is probably that he is importing the wrong package.

Comment: @ColleenLarsen, the name of the imported library is the last part of your import path, which seems to be `product` not `model`.

Comment: @Joonazan Your right, he edited the wrong package path into my answer later. Fixed it.